# Invoke SOAP dynamically using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, dynamically-generated

I m using the following code to invoke SOAP method dynamically. It works when the input for the service is ONE(1). When I increase the input to Two it returns error.

Out of idea why this happens.

I referred to this link to built this..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18950/Dynamic-Discovery-and-Invocation-of-Web-Services

My SOAP Service:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string UpdateMapString(string status, string astationid)
    {
     return string.Format("Update Completed");
    }
```

This is my C# Code Calling the SOAP service.

The main Function:

```
  private MethodInfo[] methodInfo;
        private ParameterInfo[] param;
        private Type service;
        private Type[] paramTypes;
        public List<Type> myproperty = new List<Type>();
        private string MethodName = "";
        public List<string> treews = new List<string>();
        public List<string> treeParameters = new List<string>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program a = new Program();
            a.DynamicInvocation();
            a.selectMethod();
            a.invoke();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

To Call Service:

```
  public  void DynamicInvocation()
    {
        try
        {

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:50167/Service.asmx?WSDL");

            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            System.IO.Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            // Get a WSDL file describing a service
            ServiceDescription sd = ServiceDescription.Read(requestStream);
            string sdName = sd.Services[0].Name;
            // Add in tree view
            // treeWsdl.Nodes.Add(sdName);
            treews.Add(sdName);
            Console.WriteLine("Service Name: " + sdName);

           // messageTextBox.Text += "Generating Proxy \r\n";
           // progressBar1.PerformStep();

            // Initialize a service description servImport
            ServiceDescriptionImporter servImport = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
            servImport.AddServiceDescription(sd, String.Empty, String.Empty);
            servImport.ProtocolName = "Soap";
            servImport.CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

          //  messageTextBox.Text += "Generating assembly  \r\n";
          //  progressBar1.PerformStep();

            CodeNamespace nameSpace = new CodeNamespace();
            CodeCompileUnit codeCompileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
            codeCompileUnit.Namespaces.Add(nameSpace);
            // Set Warnings
            ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warnings = servImport.Import(nameSpace, codeCompileUnit);

            if (warnings == 0)
            {
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider prov = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
                prov.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(nameSpace, stringWriter, new CodeGeneratorOptions());

           //     messageTextBox.Text += "Compiling assembly \r\n";
           //     progressBar1.PerformStep();

                // Compile the assembly with the appropriate references
                string[] assemblyReferences = new string[2] { "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Xml.dll" };
                CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
                param.GenerateExecutable = false;
                param.GenerateInMemory = true;
                param.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
                param.WarningLevel = 4;

                CompilerResults results = new CompilerResults(new TempFileCollection());
                results = prov.CompileAssemblyFromDom(param, codeCompileUnit);
                Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
                service = assembly.GetType(sdName);


                methodInfo = service.GetMethods();


                foreach (MethodInfo t in methodInfo)
                {
                    if (t.Name == "Discover")
                        break;
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);

                }
            }


            //    messageTextBox.Text += warnings;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
          //  messageTextBox.Text += "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.ToString(); ;
          //  progressBar1.Value = 70;
        }
    }
```

To get the Method:

```
 public void selectMethod()
        {

                treeParameters.Add(treews[0]);
                 MethodName = methodInfo[0].Name;
                param = methodInfo[0].GetParameters();
            /// myProperty.add = param[e.Node.Index].ParameterType;
            myproperty.Add(param[0].ParameterType);
            // Console.WriteLine("This is param: " + param[0].ToString());
            //      myProperty = new properties(param.Length);

            // Get the Parameters Type
            paramTypes = new Type[param.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
                {
                    paramTypes[i] = param[i].ParameterType;
                }

                foreach (ParameterInfo temp in param)
                {
                treeParameters.Add(temp.ParameterType.Name + "  " + temp.Name);

                }

        }
```

To Invoke Service (error in this function)

```
  public void invoke()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoke:");

            object[] param1 = new object[param.Length];

            try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
                {
                    //param1[i] = Convert.ChangeType(myProperty.MyValue[i], myProperty.TypeParameter[i]);
                 //   Console.WriteLine(myproperty[i].ToString());
                    param1[i] = Convert.ChangeType("10", typeof(string));
                }

                foreach (MethodInfo t in methodInfo)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Tname: " + t.Name.ToString());


                    if (t.Name == MethodName)
                    {
                        //Invoke Method
                        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(service);

                        //*****************error at this line
                        Object response = t.Invoke(obj, param1);
                        //*****************error at this line

                        //   Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I m having error at this line 
                        //*****************error at this line
                        Object response = t.Invoke(obj, param1);
                        //*****************error at this line